# key-mon on lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04

Does anyone know how to install key-mon on lubuntu 20.04. 
It is not in depot anymore, and when I download the .deb packet, it won't get installed because of dependencies I couldn't resolve. 
Thanks a lot ! solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still can install keymon using packages from 18.04 LTS:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/key-mon/key-mon_1.17-1ubuntu1_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./key-mon_1.17-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

---

Note: for Ubuntu 21.04 (hirsute) and 21.10 (impish) the list of dependencies is longer:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-xlib/python-xlib_0.23-2build1_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/key-mon/key-mon_1.17-1ubuntu1_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./key-mon_1.17-1ubuntu1_all.deb ./python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./python-xlib_0.23-2build1_all.deb
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Yet, I am still encountering an issue : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/julien/.local/bin/key-mon", line 2, in <module>
    import keymon.key_mon as km
  File "/home/julien/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keymon/key_mon.py", line 38
    print 'Error: Missing xlib, run sudo apt-get install python-xlib'
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('Error: Missing xlib, run sudo apt-get install python-xlib')? So I have installed python-xlib, but I also have python3-xlib and so key-mon does not start !

Comment: It looks like you have two keymons for now. Please remove one from */home/julien/.local* with its lib -   `rm /home/julien/.local/bin/key-mon`, `rm -rf /home/julien/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keymon` . And then packaged version will work.

Comment: You might want to warn people that installing this will overwrite the default python binding to python 2.7 :(

Comment: @MikeLawrence, what does it mean exactly ? My system will then use python 2.7 instead of 3.8 ?

Comment: @Videophysique it will install 2.7 if it's not already installed then link `python` to 2.7, forcing you to have to either run `python3` when you want to fire up 3 (not a bad idea as a general principle really) or reset the link yourself. I haven't bothered with the latter, and it's possible that such re-linking will break key-mon if it's not explicitly calling `python2`

Comment: @Mike Lawrence I think I am okay with the first solution, since I always call python with python3.8 - thanks !

Answer (score 6):

I could find two alternatives to keymon:

- [screenkey](https://www.thregr.org/%7Ewavexx/software/screenkey/) is packaged, maintained, but is not really useful for most screencast tasks.
- [kmcaster](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/kmcaster/) is not packaged, but the `.jar` file provided by the project should run on Ubuntu. A video compares it to key-mon:

  [image: comparison]

Comment: There is apparently a bug with french keybord in kmcaster. And I don't really screenkey appearance...But thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Yes, everybody who has been forced to use a french keyboard will confirm that there is a bug with it : - ) ... Joking aside, i think that you should fill a ticket on Github with more details on the bug you're experiencing...

Answer (score 4):

You can install key-mon as follows:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scottkirkwood/key-mon
```

You can then run it from terminal:

```
key-mon
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the following commands (solution is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwBM_ThDNpQ)):

```
$sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:nrbrtx/python2-stuff
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install key-mon
```