# Ubuntu 20.10 shift keys not working

Tags: keyboard, 20.10

I have a Dell Vostro laptop with Ubuntu 20.10 installed. Everything worked fine through Ubuntu 19.x, and the problems started with Ubuntu 20.04 and continue.  (This is not a primary work machine for me, so I've just worked on my desktop.)

The issue is that my shift keys do not work (I can't type capital letters, question marks, parentheses, etc.)  (I'm filing this report on my desktop.)

So far I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-all
```

but that tells me tha I'm at the newest version (1:7.7+19ubuntu15).

I've seen the recommendation to try the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
sudo apt-get install console-common
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data`
```

and the admonition not to do that.

I've gone into the Settings/Region & Language and made sure that I'm on the English (US) keyboard.

In any advice, please be explicit, since I'm not sure when someone says to do X, what that means always.  But I'm willing to learn.

### Thanks

Some advice I was given was to run an event listener using `xev -event keyboard` to see what's going on.  Here's the command and output:

```
$ xev -event keyboard


Outer window is 0x2600001, inner window is 0x2600002

KeymapNotify event, serial 24, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967234 0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x117, subw 0x0, time 6729494, (-77,353), root:(45,467),
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES, "   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x117, subw 0x0, time 6735520, (-77,353), root:(45,467),
    state 0x0, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x117, subw 0x0, time 6735648, (-77,353), root:(45,467),
    state 0x1, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  23  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

ClientMessage event, serial 28, synthetic YES, window 0x2600001,
    message_type 0x14d (WM_PROTOCOLS), format 32, message 0x14b (WM_DELETE_WINDOW)
```

---

When I run the same event listener on my Ubuntu 20.10 desktop (where the shift key works), I get:

```
$ xev -event keyboard Outer window is 0x7e00001, inner window is 0x7e00002

KeymapNotify event, serial 24, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967234 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    root 0x13a, subw 0x0, time 243491049, (325,434), root:(2412,558),
    state 0x10, keycode 104 (keysym 0xff8d, KP_Enter), same_screen YES, "   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    root 0x13a, subw 0x0, time 243494233, (325,434), root:(2412,558),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    root 0x13a, subw 0x0, time 243494309, (325,434), root:(2412,558),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

ClientMessage event, serial 28, synthetic YES, window 0x7e00001,
    message_type 0x144 (WM_PROTOCOLS), format 32, message 0x142 (WM_DELETE_WINDOW)
```

---

The main difference that I see is that the working desktop gives a state of

> state 0x10

and the non-working laptop gives a state of

> state 0x0

I don't know what those mean, though.

Comment: Hi Pat, open a terminal and type `xev -event keyboard` and hit the return button. Then press & release the shift key and observe what happens in the terminal. Copy the stuff from your terminal and paste it into your question (use the small **edit** link)

Comment: I am not sure how to fix it.  Ideas?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1289274/249441

Comment: Regarding key-mon, I follow the directions listed above and get

sudo apt-get install key-mon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package key-mon

Comment: Try the 18.04 package

Comment: I've tried using the 18.04 package as listed from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236194/key-mon-on-lubuntu-20-04/1289274#1289274

I get the message:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:`

 `key-mon : Depends: python-xlib but it is not installable`

`python-gtk2 : Depends: python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1) but it is not installable`

              `Depends: python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3) but it is not installable`

Comment: Temporarily Onboard (onscreen keyboard) will help to type capital letters, install it.

Comment: There are many complaints regarding dell laptop shift keys not working, try updating BIOS.   If this not works Map any other unused key to work as Shift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be worth a try (I've done some remapping of my keys this way) :
create a file in you home directory called `.Xmodmap` (note the leading dot) and add the following:

```
!Map the shift key
keycode 50 = Shift_L Shift_L Shift_L
```

Reboot

Comment: It was a Bios issue.  I was on an old bios and upgrading it to a new version fixed it.  Thank you all for your effort and your ideas.