# key-mon on lubuntu 22.04

Tags: lubuntu, 22.04

Does anyone know how to install key-mon on lubuntu 20.04? It is not in depot anymore, and when I download the `.deb` file it won't get installed because of dependencies I couldn't resolve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [key-mon on lubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236194/key-mon-on-lubuntu-20-04)

Comment: `key-mon` requires `python2` which is EOL, thus was removed from Ubuntu repositories.   Refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/key-mon for *depends*  (it also used *deprecated* GTK2 calls)